# What do I have to do to make a django project available to my company's internal network?

Tags: django

Recently I developed a simple django project to be used by my colleagues. The goal was to have the project only available within the network so no one outside the company could access it.
The company has a server, with a certain IP that will host the project.

What steps do I have to take, either in django or on the company server, to make the project available to everyone in the company? Do I have to install python in the server? I tried to put the servers IPs in allowed_hosts but it doesn't work.

Thanks for helping,
Edward

Answer (score 0):

That's a big question. [This tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-22-04) may give you some idea of what you need to do on the server, but you will obviously have to adapt to your existing project and also if you are using a different server OS.